# I am finding it hard to understand Recursion

Tags: recursion

I am finding it hard to understand Recursion. can anybody tell what's wrong in writing `cout<<` with the `print3` call..

```
    void print3(char a[],int i)
    {     
      if(a[i] == '\0')
      {
         return;
      }     
      else
      {
        cout<<print3(a,i+1);
      } 
    }
```

Comment: Well, the fact that `print3` has a return type of  `void` should be a clue.